# Jenkins job is marked as Failed, even though there are no errors in bat file execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I am calling a bat file from jenkins, in Execute Windows batch command block.

Below are the commands in this block.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set PATH=C:\OracleATS\openScript;%PATH%
cd C:\OracleATS\openScript
call runScript.bat D:\Sanity\credit_card.jwg -batchId 235
echo "done"`

After printing "done" on the console, the job status is marked as failed, even though there are no errors while running the batch file.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Learn how to format code properly! it is not readable as you posted it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins evaluates the variable `ERRORLEVEL` for success/failure on batch jobs. `ERRORLEVEL` contains the returncode last command run.

That means, if you want to catch *real* errors, you need to implement the error handling yourself in the batch, because without - only the success/failure of the last command is evaluated by jenkins and there might be valid return codes `> 0` which jenkins evaluates to failure.

try `echo Errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%` to see what you got at the end. You can do `set ERRORLEVEL=0` to have the job always success, however best practice would be to do proper error handling.

Comment: the echo shows value as 1. but there are no errors in the bat file execution. What could be the reason for errorlevel 1?

Comment: try to use `Exit 0` when your `runScript.bat` finishes successfully.